# Hudson -- pulling source from multiple version control systems

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

I want to create a new hudson job that pulls sources from two version control system cvs and svn.

Is this possible. I dont want to move from cvs stuff to svn, because we will soon be moving to git.

suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create a 'freestyle' software project you can configure it to use CVS for example.

In the build instructions you add the commands necessary to checkout the subversion sources if they are not yet checked out and update them if they are.

After these commands you add your regular build commands.

Of course the build will only trigger on the configured CVS.

To trigger on both, create a dummy project which checks out the subversion, does nothing, but configure it to trigger the first job.

I hope there are no overlapping folders/files because then you're in for a lot of fun...

good luck!